# mono embedding, get MonoClass* without knowing the namespace

Tags: c#, c, mono, mono-embedding

Given the C# sample code below it is quite easy to call the `Bar.Work` static method from C. All it takes is to obtain a `MonoClass*`, then get a `MonoMethod*` from the class and invoke it.

The thing is that in order to get the `MonoClass*` I need to provide Bar's namespace which in this case is `'sampleApp'` to the function as a parameter.

`MonoClass *klass = mono_class_from_name(image, "sampleApp", "Bar");`

The question is how can I obtain the `MonoClass*` in C if I don't know `Bar`'s class namespace. Are there any means to get a list of types inside the assembly from C? I couldn't find any examples in mono's embedding samples.

### C# sample

```
namespace sampleApp 
{

  class Bar {
    public static void Work() {
       Console.WriteLine("Bar.Work called");
    }
  }

  class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Program.Main called");
    } 
  }

}
```

### Calling `Bar.Work` from C

```
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/mono-config.h>
#include <mono/metadata/metadata.h>
#include <mono/metadata/appdomain.h>
#include <mono/metadata/class.h> 
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#include <mono/metadata/image.h>
#include <mono/metadata/object.h>
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        mono_config_parse(NULL);
 
        MonoDomain *domain = mono_jit_init_version("app", "v4.0.30319");
        MonoAssembly *assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "sampleApp.exe");  
        MonoImage *image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);  

        mono_jit_exec(domain, assembly, argc, argv);

        //how can I find Bar class if I don't know that it is under the sampleApp namespace?
        MonoClass *klass = mono_class_from_name(image, "sampleApp", "Bar");

        MonoMethod *method = mono_class_get_method_from_name(klass, "Work", 0);
        
        void *params[1] = { NULL };
        mono_runtime_invoke(method, NULL, params, NULL); 

        mono_jit_cleanup(domain, assembly);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, Unity is using fixed functions to solve this (Update(), Start()). These are the functions that unity calls, and all the other functions of the script who get called have to be in this predefined functions.

Thats one of the reasons why script names have to match with class names. They just search the folder and use the script name as class name.

Not the answer you wanted, but i think this is the best solution to this.

Comment: thanks, well i'll probably simply try to deduce the namespace from the assembly exe/dll. If it's not found then i'll let it be configured as a commandline parameter. I just have to find a class on startup once anyway.